# Data not being persisted in database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to do an update, but the data is not being persisted although i see that the hibernate query is returning the number of rows updated.

This is what I see in the logs for the number of rows updated:

- START UPDATING engagement to annuler
- DONE UPDATING engagement to annuler: 3
- Number of engagement annuler 3

However, this is not what is being reflected in the database.

I have already tried creating another class with @Component and anotating the method with @Transactional.

This is the main class

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class StatutEngagementJobAction extends GenericJobAction { 

private boolean executeAction(Tenant tenant, DateTime deadline, BigDecimal abattement, Set<DateTime> legalDays) {

  annulationEngagementNonRespecte();

}

public void annulationEngagementNonRespecte() {
        LOGGER.info("STARTING annulation engagement ");
        List<StatutEngagementDTO> annulations = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> engagementIdsToAnnuler = new ArrayList<>();
        List<StatutEngagementDTO> allEngagementNonRespecteActif = engagementDAO.findAllEngagementNonRespecteActif();

        for (StatutEngagementDTO engagementDTO : allEngagementNonRespecteActif) {
            Engagement engagementNonRespect = engagementDAO.find(engagementDTO.getIdEngagement());
                                engagementIdsToAnnuler.add(engagementNonRespect.getIdEngagement());
                    annulations.add(engagementDTO);

        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(engagementIdsToAnnuler)) {
            int num = engagementDAO.updateEngagement(engagementIdsToAnnuler);
            LOGGER.info("Number of engagement annuler {} ", num);
        }

        LOGGER.info("END annulation engagement ");
    }
```

> This method is called for update and in found in another class

```
@Override
    public int updateEngagement(List<String> engagementIdsToAnnuler){
        LOGGER.info("START UPDATING engagement to annuler ");
        String queryString =
                "UPDATE Engagement " +
                "SET etat = :etat , statut = :statut " +
                "WHERE idEngagement IN :engagementIdsToAnnuler";

        Query query = getFilteredCurrentSession().createQuery(queryString);
        query.setParameter("etat", EngagementEtatType.ACTIF);
        query.setParameter("statut", EngagementStatutType.NON_RESPECTE);
        query.setParameterList("engagementIdsToAnnuler", engagementIdsToAnnuler);

        int updatedEngagement = query.executeUpdate();
        LOGGER.info("DONE UPDATING engagement to annuler: {} ", updatedEngagement);
        return query.executeUpdate();

    }
```

> The update query is in fact working. However data is still not being persisted 
>   Actual: The data is not being persisted Expected: Data should be
>   persisted to database

Comment: Where are you calling `annulationEngagementNonRespecte`? (And why aren't you using JPA or at least JdbcTemplate?)